# select option слишком большая ширина

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<select class="select-css" style="width:150px;">
<option>This is a native select element</option>
<option>Apples</option>
<option>asdasdasdsadsad sadsads daadsadsadsdsdas dasdsd asdasdsadsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaBananas</option>
<option>Grapes</option>
<option>Oranges</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А где закрывающий тег </select>? И собственно какое поведение вы ожидаете передавая туда текст такой длинны?

Comment: @Vearo не уже ли нельзя на вторую строку поставить или уменьшить ширину?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Максимум, что вы сможете сделать - задать фон, цвет и параметры шрифта. И то не факт, что во всех браузерах сработает.

`<option>` - это примерно такая же штука, как тултип, всплывающий при наведении мыши на элемент с заданным атрибутом `title`. Рендерится системой по запросу браузера поверх всего и размерами этого элемента управлять нельзя. Хотите нормальной кастомизации - используйте реплейсеры типа jQuery UI, которые скриптом вместо вашего `<select><option>` подставят имитатор, построенный на дивах или списках. Он обстиливается как вам захочется.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ, будем учитывать в дальнейшим!